# Wrong design choice to modify local object state from Lambda in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Suppose I have this

```
Class1 instance = new Class1(); //this is "effectively final"
int [] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //array of ints

// modify "instance" with a lambda
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(x -> instance.modifyInstanceStateWithNum(x));
```

This code will work because `instance` is effectively final. I am wondering however, if this is a wrong code to use and a bad design since Lambdas from my understanding are generally functional?

The alternative is:

```
for(int num : arr){
  instance.modifyInstanceStateWithNum(num);
}
```

this does the same thing, but it "feels more right."

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(instance::modifyInstanceStateWithNum);`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Streams in java are generally terser. In its strict sense they are supposed to encourage lesser mutability and thus not changing states of your object. However, otherwise both sequential streams and a for loop does the same thing. [ref. TDD java](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pR0-DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA48&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false)

There are its disadvantages which generally people don't talk about. A for-loop is lightweight both in heap memory usage and CPU usage. If better cpu speed and heap is a priority, using a streams generally not advised.

As a newbie in programming myself, I'd still prefer to have **declarative style of programming** without evidently showing the flow of control and in fact, it "works"

> In practise you are definitely allowed to modify the state of the instance but not technically the source of the stream. You aren't allowed to modify the data source during the execution of the stream function [javase8.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description)

So basically as an example : This is fine : based on your code:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(x -> instance.modifyInstanceStateWithNum(x));
```

But something like this isn't :

```
List<Pojo> pojos; //some pojo
pojos.stream().forEach(pojo-> pojos.remove(pojo)); //THIS ISN'T RIGHT
```

To sum up your doubt, It depends on what you are doing is correct or not and how you feel the code should be and focus more on code readability, efficiency and for thousands of lines of code I honestly prefer a `lambda functions` over a generic for-loop as long as "it works" and any one can easily understand what I have tried to do.

This also aligns in conjunction with FP-oriented programming is about and looks like as programming languages evolve this is respected.

Comment: Who are you quoting?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for `Stream.foreach()` gives appropriate warnings:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic. For parallel stream pipelines, this operation does not guarantee to respect the encounter order of the stream, as doing so would sacrifice the benefit of parallelism. For any given element, the action may be performed at whatever time and in whatever thread the library chooses. If the action accesses shared state, it is responsible for providing the required synchronization.

So there are a lot of things to keep in mind when using `forEach()`. But as long as you don't use parallel streams and keep the side effects small, simple operations should be fine.

The fact that `Stream` has a `forEach` method at all (which makes no sense without side effects) hints that it is not thought of as completely out of order.

Personally, my vote would be for using a for loop if streams don't gain you a significant advantage in readability.